# mysql_affected_rows to figure out the type of query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a utility class in my php code which provides wrapper for some mysql functions. One of the functions named `query()` accepts the query string as an argument and then performs that query. 
In this query function I want to find out if the given query is data state changing query `(UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE etc.)` or a simple data extraction query `(SHOW/SELECT)`.

I was planning to use `mysql_affected_rows` function for this as the php manual says this function "Gets the number of affected rows by the `last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query`".

I was assuming I would get a 0 or null for SELECT query. I know even those `UPDATE/DELETE` queries which do not make any modifications will return 0 but it's ok from my code perspective because I only want to identify those queries which actually did some data modification.

But when I actually executed the code, `mysql_affected_rows` returns me the number of selected rows for SELECT queries.

Is it the expected behavior? I looked up php manuals but they do not elaborate on what would be the behavior of `mysql_affected_rows` in case of SELECT queries.

I looked up MySql documentation and it says MySql `mysql_affected_rows` function is expected to work like `mysql_num_rows` (which is consistent with the behavior I am seeing).

So is there any other php function which can help me identify the query type without actually parsing the query?

Comment: First, please stop using the `mysql_` extensions as they are deprecated and will be going away. Second, as you have seen, this is expected behavior for `mysql_affected_rows`. In the docs for the `mysqli_` functions it states, "For SELECT statements mysqli_affected_rows() works like mysqli_num_rows()." You could use `mysqli_info` and then interpret the results - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php

Comment: Unfortunately this is some legacy code and I am stuck with using mysql_ extension.

Comment: Also mysql_info is not going to work here because it does not distinguish between DELETE and SELECT queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you trying too complicated, string parsing isn't the worst idea here.

Or do you know any query not beginning with what it's doing?

Multiqueries **are not available** in `mysql_query` anyways.

```
public function query($query) {
    $state = null;

    if (stripos(trim($query), 'INSERT') === 0) {
        $state = 'insert';
    }
    elseif (stripos(trim($query), 'REPLACE') === 0) {

    }
    elseif (stripos(trim($query), 'UPDATE') === 0) {

    }
    elseif (stripos(trim($query), 'SELECT') === 0) {
        $state = 'select';
    }
    elseif (stripos(trim($query), 'SET') === 0) {
        $state = 'option';
    }
    else {
        $state = '?';
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I am looking for some solution other than string parsing.  String parsing was my first option. However I thought if I could find an in-built function which could give me this information, it would be more reliable.  For example for queries which have an inline comment in the beginning, would break my parsing logic. e.g. - /*some comment*/ SELECT * FROM mytable

Comment: If you have an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` for example, effected rows will be returning wrong results. Neither way is reliable!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extract the first word of the sql (string) that the function query receives and perform a comparison condition to the operations

```
$sql = 'select * from tableName';
$action = explode(' ',trim($sql))[0];
$action = strtoupper($action);

if($action=='UPDATE' || $action == 'INSERT' || $action=='DELETE'){
    //do your stuff here
}else{
    //it's a show/select query.
}
```

ps: this is not a working/tested code. just an example to better explain what i'm talking about.